# After clicking alt-tab CWM still send keys to previous window

Tags: ubuntu, window-managers

Just want to check if anyone else stumbled upon this problem. I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 with openbsd-cwm instead of xfce4. Randomly when I alt-tab, the keyboard is still sending keys to the previously shown window. Is this a known issue?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ might be better forums for this question.

Comment: @tk421 Yes, maybe. Thank you for the tip.